# How to pick a constraint function for Lagrangian mechanics?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, constrained-dynamics

### Motivating Example

Consider a system which consists of two masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ at positions $x_1$ and $x_2$ respectively joined together by a rigid rod of negligible mass and length $l$ . We have the Lagrangian
$$
L = \frac{1}{2} m_1 \dot{x}_1^2 + \frac{1}{m} m_2 \dot{x}_2^2
$$
and the obvious constraint
$$
x_2 - x_1 - l = 0 \label{con1}\tag{1}
$$
which yields the equations of motion:
\begin{align}
m_1 \ddot{x}_1 + \lambda &= 0 \\
m_2 \ddot{x}_2 - \lambda &= 0
\end{align}
for some function of time $\lambda$. These are the expected equations of motion with $\lambda$ playing the role of tension in the rod.

What stops us from choosing instead the constraint
$$
(x_2 - x_1 - l)^2 = 0 \label{con2}\tag{2}
$$
which has exactly the same solutions in $x_1 , x_2$ as \ref{con1}? We then get the equations of motion:
\begin{align}
m_1 \ddot{x} + 2\lambda (x_2 - x_1 - l) &= 0 \\
m_2 \ddot{x} - 2\lambda (x_2 - x_1 - l) &= 0
\end{align}
These equations of motion look like what we would expect if $m_1$ and $m_2$ were joined by a spring with spring constant $2\lambda$.

### My Question

Above I obtained physically distinct equations of motion by using different constraints with identical solution sets.

If the solution set of a constraint doesn't uniquely determine the physics, what does? How do I pick the "right" constraint? What information do I have to use beyond the solution set of the constraint?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109398/2451

Comment: So is the motion constrained to one dimension?

Comment: @J.G. In the example, yes.

Comment: @Qmechanic thank you for the link. That didn't come up when I searched. Tips for finding possible duplicates?